# Global Picklists: Apex assignment

Tags: apex, picklist

I'm currently developing an update to our application inside a sandbox using the new feature of `Global Picklists`. Unfortunately I can't simply assign one exact picklist value (exposed as a string) in Apex to the field associated with the global picklist, as it throws the error:

> **INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST**

Comment: check this https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093WSIAY

Comment: thanks for the help, but this particular page doesn't really help - I have made sure the string contains the exact picklist value - I already made several apex updates with "classical" picklists and never faced such an error

Comment: I even tried it using values from the `PicklistEntry` class ([PicklistEntry Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm) which essentially gives me the same string value as my initial try) via the `getValue()` method - It really seems like a bug...

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, still no answer and it isn't working by now.

Comment: Curious if this was ever fixed? Running into same thing. Using global pick list. All record types configured to use all values. Apex Tests throw error on assigning legitimate value on Account insert.